# Get Global Const to autocomplete in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, global-variables, constants

I was under the assumption that the entire point of constants was to avoid typos and make life easier....but thats not so true if I cant get const to auto suggest in classes they are available in. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDefaultsConstants : NSObject

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const user_full_name;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const user_first_name;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const user_last_name;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const user_cover_photo;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const user_default_photo;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const user_udid;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const session_draft_status_text;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString* const session_draft_image_url;

@end
#import "NSDefaultsConstants.h"

@implementation NSDefaultsConstants

@end


NSString* const user_full_name = @"user_fullname";
NSString* const user_first_name = @"user_first_name";
NSString* const user_last_name = @"user_last_name";
NSString* const user_cover_photo = @"user_cover_photo";
NSString* const user_default_photo = @"user_default_photo";
NSString* const user_udid = @"user_udid";

NSString* const session_draft_status_text = @"session_draft_status_text";
NSString* const session_draft_image_url = @"session_draft_image_url";
```

[image]

Comment: I get const in my autocomplete suggestions, not sure what may go wrong.

Comment: Try replacing FOUNDATION_EXPORT with extern.